# Looking for driver animation like Uber in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uianimation

I want an make an animation like when app starts looking for the drivers when circle is increasing and decreasing. [image]

Here is my code I am increasing and decreasing the width and height of the circle in autoreverse animation but it has 2 problems:

1. Its not working like the animation is happening from center. Its beginning and end from a corner.
2. Radius of the circle doesn't remain consistent. It turns into a square when its closing

Code:

```
let duration = 2.0


UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse] , animations: {
        let cntr = self.circularView.center
        self.circularView.layer.cornerRadius = min(self.circularView.frame.size.height,self.circularView.frame.size.width)/2
        self.circularView.center = cntr
        self.circularView.frame.size.width = (self.circularView.frame.size.width) * 2
        self.circularView.frame.size.height = (self.circularView.frame.height) * 2
```

Comment: You better check https://github.com/shu223/Pulsator, https://github.com/YGeorge/YGPulseView

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Leave the corner radius outside of the animation. Animate with a transform instead of changing the width or constraints. In your storyboard/code set the position of your circular views with center related constraints :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.circularView!.layer.cornerRadius = self.circularView!.frame.width / 2

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse] , animations: {
        self.isZooming = !self.isZooming
        var zoomTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        let scale: CGFloat = self.isZooming ? 0.5 : 1.5
        zoomTransform = zoomTransform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
        self.circularView?.transform = zoomTransform
    })
}
```

[image] 
[image]